# Redirect from Chrome to Android app blocked after 302 with location header

Tags: android, google-chrome, redirect, oauth, http-status-code-302

I have an issue with redirect to Android app after redirect callback 302.

After receiving redirect 302 from the website after authentication I want to open Android app. So I set response header for redirect to my app:

`location: myapp://open`.

For majority of cases it works, but for one institution authentication Chrome is blocking redirect and it says in console:

`navigation is blocked: myapp://open`

Chrome version: 79.0.03945.93

iOS works smoothly with all cases.
Does anyone knows what could be the issue and possible workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed on version 81 of Chrome, they had a regression bug on 79 & 80.